# Do I need additional gems or maybe need to run a prior version of a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, cloud9-ide

Do I need additional gems or maybe need to run a prior version of a gem?

I am using `cloud9` and trying to deploy on `heroku`. I have added 'pg' gem (specifically '0.17.1' and gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2' within group :production)  as well as ruby "2.2.1" at the top of the list - which is what successfully established my connection to heroku for the first time after a bunch of attempts.

Unfortunately my app doesn't seem to be working at full. It is missing essentially all of the content on heroku (it still displays the navbar and sign up/log in but nothing functions) but on the `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` on cloud9 my app has everything.

I am updating my repository on bitbucket.org. I am wondering if maybe something needs to be undone or "rolled back" through all of the command cycles I have run through. Need I say these have been the common commands I've been using:

```
gem install pg

bundle install

git add .

git commit -a -m "Update Gemfile.lock"

git push

git push heroku master

heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I tried updating my `config/database.yml` with postgresql but haven't found any success. Honestly, I don't know if I'm asking the correct question that corresponds to the apparent issue, but any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the logs on Heroku. Is there any visible error?

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
heroku login
```

then:

```
heroku create
```

Next, just `add`, `commit` and write `git push heroku master` for the first time to have git push to heroku.